# Not able to use MySQL commands after installation

Tags: macos, command-line, permissions, mysql

I have installed MySQL successfully (on Mac OS X) and am at the point where I want to create/show databases. MySQL Server Status says it's running but when I try to run mysql commands from /usr/local/mysql I get the error

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'Username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am trying the command:

> mysql> SHOW DATABASES

but still encountering this error and have done research to avoid this and came upon using this command to avoid granting permission

> mysqld --skip-grant-tables

after running this command I get another error saying

> mysqld: Can't change dir to '/usr/local/mysql-5.7.13-osx10.11->x86_64/data/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
>
> 2016-08-16T18:42:00.489762Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT >value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server >option (see documentation for more details).
>
> 2016-08-16T18:42:00.490049Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for -->secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated >files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path...

I've been going in circles researching error after error and feel that I'm close but just missing one or a few key things. Please help me fix this!

Answer (score 1):

To access Mysql without password you need to run it in safe mode.

1) Stop mysql

```
# service mysql stop
```

2) Run it in safe mode with the option you mentioned:

```
# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

3) Check if it is running in safe mode:

```
# pgrep -l mysql
```

you will see something like

```
2515 mysqld_safe
2875 mysqld
```

4) Now you can enter as a root without password:

```
# mysql -uroot
```

Comment: When I type these commands in my terminal, there is no result. I'm typing exactly as you described "# pgrep -l mysql" and it's just going back to command the command line path as if I just hit enter with nothing in it. @Oleg_Bolden